# How do I check if a user is Authorized?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In the log in section of my website, in order for the user to log in then their email needs to have been confirmed. If it is confirmed then the SignInAsync method is called.

Normally this would be fine but there are certain areas of the website that "General Users" cannot access. So I used

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
```

above all controllers that the user cannot access. My problem now is in the event that user would type in a link that they do not have access to, because of that Authorize attribute would require a user that has an admin role to log in. And when a general user tries logging in, then it just refreshes the log in page. I need a way to check if the user is authorized (not authenticated) but authorized so that I can display an appropriate error message. This is the code i have currently:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.EmailConfirmed == true)
        {
            //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe); return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Confirm Email Address.");
            model.ErrorMessage = ("You need to confirm your email address in order to log in, please check yout emails");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        model.ErrorMessage = "Username or password is incorrect"; 
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I have looked for answers for this online but all the websites i found have solutions to checking if the user is authenticated(logged in) and not chcecking if the user is authorized, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Can you try using if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { your code }

Comment: I dont seem to have that option, Also, wouldnt that just check if the user is logged in and not if the user has access to that page?

Comment: You should authorize based on roles(Admin, Employees, other etc..), there are multiple ways to do it. if you want to authenticate then above mentioned my code should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The other websites made it seem like checking if the user is authenticated is the same as checking if the user is logged it but it also checks if the user have the correct defined role. e.g "Admin". Therefore, the following code

```
if (user.EmailConfirmed == true)
{
    if (USER.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Authorization", "You are not authorized to access this section of the website");
    }

}
```

will check if the user's email is confirmed and if they are authorized to check that section of the page, and it will display an error message if they are not.